# Double Slit Experiment

Tags: measurement

Does anyone know if is possible to run one instance of this experiment with two groups of people. One group who is able to observe while the other group is somehow not and still get the expected results?

The 'expected' results would be: unobserved where you would get the wave pattern and observed which shows two lines.

Also what happens if you mix it up and add two photon beam sources and more slits some of them observed and some not. I'm not sure what this would prove but curious to see what different patterns are produced in different scenarios. Would the presence of a camera on another experiment change the results of another unobserved experiment?

Comment: It’s not really that clear how this relates to quantum *computing*. Perhaps consider asking at physics.stackexchange.com?